# Как реализовать прыжок элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery, разработка-игр

Всем привет! Есть элемент **#circle** и по нажатию на кнопку, она должна двигаться вправо, до определенного места, и при нажатии на пробел, движущийся элемент должен      прыгать. У меня проблемы с прыжком, он  работает до нажатия кнопки старт, а после нажатия кнопки не работает, думаю из-за очередности функции, все что я пробовал не сработало. Спасибо!

```js
$(function(){

    var jump = false;

    $('button').click(function(){

        var trackWidth = 1250;
        var start = true;
        var value = 0;
        var intervalID = setInterval(moveCircle, 1);

        function moveCircle(){
            value +=10;

            $('#circle').animate( { marginLeft: value }, 50 );

            if (value === trackWidth) {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }

        }
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            jump = true;
            $('#circle').animate({ top: -100 }, {duration: 300});
            $('#circle').animate({ top: 0 }, {duration: 300}, function(){
                jump = false;
            });
        }
    });

});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

body {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#track {
    margin-top: 10%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #39f590;
    border: 2px solid #50ce8a; 
}

button {
    font: 1.2em Arial;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #39f590;
    border: 1px solid #50ce8a;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background: #39f590;
    color: white;
}


#circle {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 130px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "circle.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "track">
        <div id = "circle"></div>
    </div>

    <button>Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

С `JQuery` можно сделать многое, но есть и другие фреймворки, в том числе и для создания игр. Вашу задачу можно решить на чистом `js`, для начала прочтите [туториал](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation) (если еще не читали). Если нужно что-то сложнее - полистайте [JavaScript game engines](https://github.com/showcases/javascript-game-engines).